# templateUrl changes when refresh or reload page in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angular packet template. Here 11 pages loaded and 11 different buttons like the following:

[image]

Here is the route code:

```
state('app.pagelayouts.fixedsidebar1', {
  url: "/fixed-sidebar",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/page-1.html",
  resolve: loadSequence('d3', 'ui.knob', 'countTo', 'dashboardCtrl'),
  title: 'Fixed Sidebar',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
      label: 'Fixed Sidebar'
  },
  controller: function ($scope) {
    $scope.setLayout();
    $scope.app.layout.isSidebarFixed = true;

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',function(){
      $scope.templateUrl = $route.current.templateUrl;
    })
  }
})
.state('app.pagelayouts.fixedsidebar2', {
  url: "/fixed-sidebar",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/page-2.html",
  resolve: loadSequence('d3', 'ui.knob', 'countTo', 'dashboardCtrl'),
  title: 'Fixed Sidebar',
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Fixed Sidebar'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.setLayout();
    $scope.app.layout.isSidebarFixed = true;
  }
}).
```

page-3.html, page-4.html  and so on....

Suppose I am in page-1.html, when I refresh it doesn't stay in page-1. Goes to another page. But it should be stay at page-1.html. The `templateUrl` is changing.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Please show sample of other states. Maybe you have same url for them?

Comment: You can [edit] the question to add more info in it rather than comments. I've added it in question for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot T J .You gave me the hint . I changes the url url: "/fixed-sidebar", .Set url: "/fixed-sidebar1",url: "/fixed-sidebar2", and so on .
Now its working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you have same `url` for all the routes.
You should update it with a parameter indicating the template to load, so that when page is refreshed, UI Router knows which state to activate based on the url. For example:

```js
state('app.pagelayouts.fixedsidebar1', {
  url: "/fixed-sidebar/1",
  templateUrl: "assets/views/page-1.html",
  resolve: loadSequence('d3', 'ui.knob', 'countTo', 'dashboardCtrl'),
  title: 'Fixed Sidebar',
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Fixed Sidebar'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.setLayout();
    $scope.app.layout.isSidebarFixed = true;
  }
});
```

If all your routes are similar, you can create a single route with a param like:

```js
state('app.pagelayouts.fixedsidebar', {
  url: "/fixed-sidebar/:id",
  templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
    return "assets/views/page-" + $stateParams.id + ".html";
  },
  resolve: loadSequence('d3', 'ui.knob', 'countTo', 'dashboardCtrl'),
  title: 'Fixed Sidebar',
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: 'Fixed Sidebar'
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.setLayout();
    $scope.app.layout.isSidebarFixed = true;
  }
});
```